# Convert DTO to an array of DTO's

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a project where I have this response as an output.

```
  "data": {
            "PERCENT_INTERES": 0.9,
            "TERM": 1
        }
```

I have this DTO where the result is set

```
public class ContractDTO {

    @JsonProperty("PERCENT_INTERES")
    private Float percent;
    @JsonProperty("TERM")
    private Integer term;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

But now I need to get as a result an array of that DTO. I tried with this DTO to make a list of dto's, but it doesn't work.

```
public class ContractArrayDTO {

    public List<ContractDTO> result;

    public List<ContractDTO> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<ContractDTO> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

The logic of the service. The service was prepared to return a ContractDTO which is an object.

```
 ContractDTO res = new ContractDTO();
 res.setTerm(1);
 res.setPercent(0,9);
```

Is there a way to convert that response to an array?

The result I want is the one below, not an array of objects.

```
 "data": { [PERCENT_INTERES: 0.9, TERM: 1] }
```

Comment: Have you tried to return list<ContractDto> instead of wrapper class ContractArrayDto?

Comment: Create list and add to the list

Answer (score 1):

As you get the response correctly, just built the result as `List`.

```
List<ContractDTO> dtos = Arrays.asList(new ContractDTO(), new ContractDTO());

// or
List<ContractDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
dtoList.add(new ContractDTO());
dtoList.add(new ContractDTO());
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it works nicely. But if I have to convert the key-pair values of the object into an array. How would it be?

Comment: If you key-pair values is an array, it could be convert to List. But your response `"data": { "PERCENT_INTERES": 0.9, "TERM": 1 }` is not an array, so convert it to a dto and then build a result of List.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `list.toArray()` method.

```
    List<ContractDTO> c = List.of( new ContractDTO(), new ContractDTO() );
    ContractDTO[] result = c.toArray( new ContractDTO[0] );
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( result ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simply return `List<ContractDTO>` only (you don't need the custom wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping(value="/get")
    public List<ContractDTO> get() {
        List<ContractDTO> list=new ArrayList<>();

        ContractDTO dto=new  ContractDTO();
        dto.setPercent((float) 1.24);
        dto.setTerm(1);
        list.add(dto);


        dto=new  ContractDTO();
        dto.setPercent((float) 1.44);
        dto.setTerm(2);
        list.add(dto);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just return dto in above code and change List<ContractDTO> to ContractDTO  in return type.

Comment: but the contract dto is an object, with jsonproperties

Comment: You want to create custom json and then want to return? Please provide example.

Comment: ContractDTO is an object, but I want to instead of returning ```"data": {
            "PERCENT_INTERES": 0.9,
            "TERM": 1
        }``` the desire result would be ```"data": {
            ["PERCENT_INTERES": 0.9,
            "TERM": 1]
        }```